# Gamma correction on mycolor

Tags: color

How to add a Gamma correction like  `gamma[x_?NumericQ, ɣ_] := x^(1/ɣ)` to my color function ?

```
data = Table[{#, #2, Sin[#] Cos[#2]} & @@ RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2], {1000}];

myTemperatureMap[f_] := Blend[
  { {0., Blue}, {.25, Lighter@LightBlue}, {.25, White}
  , {.75, White}, {.75, Yellow}, {1., Red}
  }
, f]; 

DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
, PlotPoints -> 100
, ColorFunction -> myTemperatureMap
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A color like `Brown` is a [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html) expression, with arguments you can manipulate with standard tools, e.g. [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
Table[MapAt[#^(1/γ) &, Brown, ;; 3], {γ, {0.4, 1, 2.2}}]
```

[image]

```
gamma[γ_][c_?ColorQ] := MapAt[#1^(1/γ) &, ColorConvert[c, "RGB"], ;; 3]

myTM[γ_] := 
    gamma[γ] @ Blend[{{0., Blue}, {.25, Lighter@LightBlue}, {.25, White},
       {.75, White}, {.75, Yellow}, {1., Red}}, #] &;

DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> myTM[0.1], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> myTM[2.2], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

#### With array data

```
data = {#, #2, Sin[#] Cos[#2]} & @@@ RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {8000, 2}];

ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> myTM[0.1], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks if my data is a list of 3 column how to change it because when I change the func sin[x]*cos[y] by my data it doesn’t work

Comment: @Bigprophete `ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> myTM[2.2], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]` ?

Comment: @creidhne I tried this `ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> myTM[0.1], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: @Bigprophete I'm not sure I understand. Please see my update.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Seems to be working thanks a lot